# Prevent form from stealing focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When I run my VB.NET Winforms app I do not want it to steal the focus from the other open apps.  FYI, my app is started from the command line but that shouldn't make a difference.  I've seen question [577076](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577076/topmost-window-form-steal-focus) but that doesn't seem to work.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did to get this working:

I added the following code to my Form1.vb file:

```
Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowWithoutActivation() As Boolean  
    Get  
        Return True  
    End Get  
End Property
```

But still no success.

Then I unchecked the Enable Application Framework checkbox on the Application tab of the project properties.

Success!!!

Comment: Here is an article on ShowWithoutActivation()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showwithoutactivation.aspx

Comment: Did not work form me. Mine is console app so that option is unchecked by default

Answer (score 1):

Actually the ShowWithoutActivation works and without having to disable the framework.  I was thinking my issue was not working until I realized hiding the main form was causing focus back on it when popup form came up.  Thus taking focus off my other applications I was working with.  If you are running into a similar situation, use opacity instead of hide.   Just set to 0 to hide the form and 100 to bring it back. This allows the function to work as described.

Comment: does 0 opacity cause clicks to bypass the window?

Comment: at 0, the form is not present to be clicked.   It essentially acts as hide without the shortcomings.

Comment: that's a great hack

Answer (score 0):

In the example you linked, some constants are declared outside the scope of the method. Here is another version that should work for you:

```
protected CreateParams CreateParams {
  get {
    CreateParams baseParams = base.CreateParams;
    const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;   
    const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;    
    baseParams.ExStyle |= (int) (WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW); 
    return baseParams;
  }
}
...
```

You're gonna have to translate it to VB.Net though...

Comment: Thanks Julien, you did answer my original question but that still didn't work to prevent form from stealing focus.  I edited my question to make it clearer.