# MSN Messenger like notification - Do you know any examples in .NET VB .NET or C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, notifications, taskbar

I'm looking to write a notification application where I'd like to provide popup notifications from the taskbar similiar to the ones in MSN Messenger or most other chat programs.  Are there any good examples using VB .NET or C#, ideally without using Win32 calls?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution for what I'm looking to to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163732.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try this, modeled after Outlook rather than MSN Messenger, but of course you can still tweak it:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c10139

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/RobMisNotifyWindow.aspx

Comment: I found this example online.  I'm trying to avoid using Win32 calls.

Comment: As mentioned in the article, the only way to show the window without stealing focus is the Win32 ShowWindow method. So you can't really avoid Win32 and get the behavior you want.

Comment: Took a bit of digging but I found this reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showwithoutactivation.aspx

as well as this SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630420/prevent-form-from-stealing-focus/631082

Looks like you can prevent the focus from being stolen without Win32 calls :-D

Answer (score 0):

Also known as toast notifications. [Here's another example on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/myalerts.aspx).

Slightly off-topic. I think these things are evil. I wish they were never invented because they always pop up at at time when it is most distracting. S[ee human task switching considered harmful](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000022.html).

And for the love of mike, please detect [presentation mode](http://blogs.technet.com/james/archive/2006/09/11/455407.aspx) and stop putting up toasts. (Do you hear me skype?!)